# How do I retrieve the text from a file using IndexOf and SubString ? It dosen't work 

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
private void retrivingText1()
{
   string startTag = "zethrone1_03510";//"<Translation>";
   string endTag = "-2.8";//"</Translation>";

   int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
   int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
   index = 0;

   w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\retrivedText1.txt");

   while (true)
   {
      index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);

      if (index == -1)
      {
         break;
      }

      // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
      int start = index + startTagWidth;
      index = f.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);

      if (index == -1)
      {
         break;
      }

      // found the endTag 
      string g = f.Substring(start, index - start);
      w.WriteLine(g);
   }

   w.Close();
}
```

The first work in the file that I want to retrieve is `Hallo?` which is coming right after `zethrone1_03510` but between `zethrone1_03510` and `Hallo?` there are two spaces so I'm getting it in the new text file like this   `Hallo?`

And I want it to be `Hallo?` without the two spaces after `zethrone1_03510` that's one problem.

The second problem is that in the end of the file there is a text `-2.8` so I want to retrieve all the text from the first `Hallo?` including it until the end of the file or until the last `-2.8` including it too. Since there are more places after the `Hallo?` with `-2.8`

I tried to use `LastIndexOf` instead of `IndexOf` but it didn't work.

And I know there are other ways but I want to do it with my code to fix/repair my code not using another way of codes. Whats wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use an XML file because you write about tags?

Comment: And what is variable f? You use `f.IndexOf(startTag, index);` But I never see f declared.

Comment: SynerCode nope startTag and endTag was since i used it before with another file. But the file im reading from now i .BIN and the variable f is declared in the top form level and i use it in the constructor to read to the end the .BIN file. f is a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem you could use the Trim() method to get rid of the space. you could Trim your resulting string like: `(" Hallo").Trim();` or `variable.Trim();` which results in "Hallo".

LastIndexOf should work with your second problem . You could use int position = f.LastIndexOf (endTag); And after you found the text you should break from the loop so you don't have an endless loop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx

```
private void retrivingText1()
{
    string startTag = "zethrone1_03510";//"<Translation>";
    string endTag = "-2.8";//"</Translation>";
    int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
    int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
    index = 0;
    w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\retrivedText1.txt");
    while (true)
    {
        index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
        int start = index + startTagWidth;
        index = f.LastIndexOf (endTag, start + 1);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // found the endTag 
        string g = f.Substring(start, index - start + endTagWidth).Trim(); //Trim the founded text so the start and ending spaces are removed.
        w.WriteLine(g);
        //break so you dont have an endless loop
        break;
    }
    w.Close();
}
```

Comment: The second problem is that after the "Hallo?" there is a lot of more text and the text end i mean the file and also the text end with the word "-2.8" the -2.8 is part of the text. I want to retrive all the text from "Hallo?" to the "-2.8" including the -2.8 the problem is that between the "Hallo?" and the end of the file there are more places the word "-2.8" is sppears so its retriving the text from the "Hallo?" untill the first "-2.8" he find and not untill the last "-2.8" wich is in the end of the text/file.  therfore he retriving only part of the text and not untill the end.

Comment: The Trim() didnt work. i changed it to string startTag = "Hallo?".Trim(); and it just didnt show the "Hallo?" at all wich is not good. and before it i did string startTag = "zethrone1_03510".Trim(); but it didnt solve it.

Comment: SynerCode this line index = f.LastIndexOf (endTag, start + 1); in the edited example make it get into the IF and its doing the break; so the file created is empty.